# how do i know my ethereum nodes sync low speed or out of sync

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth, quorum

I build four quorum node , i want to detect which node sync too low or out of sync.

I think it can be compared using the block number. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check the current blockNumber (use `eth.blockNumber` in the geth console).
Note that if the node is out of sync then `eth.syncing` should give more info.